# Why I get "global name ... is not defined"?

Tags: python

I have two pieces of code, one is made to get word scores and the other is intended to test it. But I get

```
NameError: global name 'wordList' is not defined
```

This is the first file ps4a.py.

```
# ps4a.py
import random
import string
HAND_SIZE = 7
SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES = {
'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 3, 'd': 2, 'e': 1, 'f': 4, 'g': 2, 'h': 4, 'i': 1, 'j': 8,
'k': 5, 'l': 1, 'm': 3, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 3, 'q': 10, 'r': 1, 's': 1, 't': 1,
'u': 1, 'v': 4, 'w': 4, 'x': 8, 'y': 4, 'z': 10
}
WORDLIST_FILENAME = "C:/Users/erroric/mit/ProblemSet4/words.txt"
def loadWords():
    # inFile: file
    inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r', 0)
    # wordList: list of strings
    wordList = []
    for line in inFile:
        wordList.append(line.strip().lower())
    print "  ", len(wordList), "words loaded."
    return wordList
def getWordScore(word, n):
    score = 0
    bonus = 50
    if word in wordList:
        for i in word:
            score += SCRABBLE_LETTER_VALUES.get(i)
        score *= len(word)
    else :
        print "That is not a valid word. Please choose another word"

if len(word) == n:
    score += bonus
return score

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wordList = loadWords()
    playGame(wordList)
```

test file

```
from ps4a import *

#
# Test code
# You don't need to understand how this test code works (but feel free to look it over!)

# To run these tests, simply run this file (open up in IDLE, then run the file as normal)

def test_getWordScore():
    """
    Unit test for getWordScore
    """
    failure=False
    # dictionary of words and scores
    words = {("", 7):0, ("it", 7):4, ("was", 7):18, ("scored", 7):54, ("waybill", 7):155, 
    ("outgnaw", 7):127, ("fork", 7):44, ("fork", 4):94}
    for (word, n) in words.keys():
        score = getWordScore(word, n)
        if score != words[(word, n)]:
            print "FAILURE: test_getWordScore()"
            print "\tExpected", words[(word, n)], "points but got '" \
            + str(score) + "' for word '" + word + "', n=" + str(n)
            failure=True
    if not failure:
        print "SUCCESS: test_getWordScore()"

wordList = loadWords()
print "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
print "Testing getWordScore..."
test_getWordScore()
```

words.txt is in [wods.txt in this zip](http://www.xuetangx.com/c4x/MITx/6_00_1x/asset/ProblemSet4.zip)

I want to test `getWordScore()` but I get
`NameError: global name 'wordList' is not defined`

Comment: Is the indentation in your first file really like that? Seems odd...

Comment: where do you think WordList is coming from in `if word in wordList:`?

Comment: I just get wordList in loadWords() ,and if the word is in wordList, then get the word score

Comment: @erroric, I meant it does not exist  in the scope of the function you are calling, not when you import the functions .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `wordList` in `getWordScore`:

```
def getWordScore(word, n):
        score = 0
        bonus = 50
        wordList = loadWords() # create wordList
        if word in wordList:
```

Or make wordList a parameter and pass it in:

```
def getWordScore(WordList, word, n):
```

The  ps4a.py code works because the wordList is created if the script itself is run so it exists in the global namespace.

A hack to run your code would be to use the module to add wordList:

```
def test_getWordScore():
    """
    Unit test for getWordScore
    """
    failure=False
    # dictionary of words and scores
    words = {("", 7):0, ("it", 7):4, ("was", 7):18, ("scored", 7):54, ("waybill", 7):155,
    ("outgnaw", 7):127, ("fork", 7):44, ("fork", 4):94}
    for (word, n) in words.keys():
        score = getWordScore(word, n)
        if score != words[(word, n)]:
            print "FAILURE: test_getWordScore()"
            print "\tExpected", words[(word, n)], "points but got '" \
            + str(score) + "' for word '" + word + "', n=" + str(n)
            failure=True
    if not failure:
        print "SUCCESS: test_getWordScore()"

import ps4a
ps4a.wordList = loadWords()

print "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
print "Testing getWordScore..."
test_getWordScore()
```

Or use the `__builtin__`:

```
import __builtin__
__builtin__.wordList = loadWords()
```

global variables are only global in the module they are created in.

Comment: I know the code writen by you, but the parameters of getWordScore is limited as getWordScore(word, n).

Answer (score -1):

Add line,

`global wordList`
in a function where you want to use it.

Comment: Can someone explain me, what is wrong with above answer?

Comment: Some might consider `global` a bad programming practice, but I guess the downvoter had other motivations, otherwise a simple comment would have worked better.

Comment: Ha, I provided what question demanded. I know that it's a bad practice.

Comment: If it helps, my answer got the downvote too. I'm writing it off as a loss and moving on ;)

Comment: global won't work, variables are only global in the namespace that they exist in.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [global](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#global) keyword to access variables outside the scope of the current function:

```
def getWordScore(word, n):
    global worldList
```